# how to implement recaptcha in expo web?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, recaptcha

Im trying to implement recaptcha in expo web but keep getting errors. How do I implement recaptcha in expo web? Do I use html and scripts?

I've tried to use Webview (react-native-web-webview) and added config in webpack.config but keep getting error *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'postMessage')*

**Note: react-native-web-webview uses iframe for web.**

```
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

 const getWebviewContent = () => {
        var originalForm = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script></head><body><form action="[POST_URL]" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="[TITLE]"><input type="hidden" value="[DESCRIPTION]"><input type="hidden" value="[URL]"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<site-key>"></div><input type="submit" value="Send"/></form></body></html>'
        var tmp = originalForm
            .replace("[POST_URL]", "http://localhost:19006/Contact")
            .replace("[TITLE]", 'title')
            .replace("[DESCRIPTION]", 'description')
            .replace("[URL]", 'http://localhost:19006/Contact');

        return tmp;

    }

 <WebView
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     mixedContentMode={'always'}
     style={{ height: 500, width: 500 }}
     source={{
     html: getWebviewContent(),
     baseUrl: '<domain>' // <-- SET YOUR DOMAIN HERE
   }} />
```

I've also tried to use libraries and still getting the same error

```
import Recaptcha from 'react-native-recaptcha-that-works';
  <Recaptcha
      ref={recaptcha}
      siteKey="<site-key>"
      baseUrl="http://localhost:19006/Contact"
      onVerify={onVerify}
      onExpire={onExpire}
      onError={(err) => {
      alert('onError event');
      console.warn(JSON.stringify(err));
      }}
      size="normal"
      />
```